# The M2 brane of M theory creates the Type IIA string and D2; the M5 brane creates the D4 and NS5. What are the other objects grouped with the D0?

Tags: string-theory, gravitational-waves, branes, compactification

Type IIA string theory is related to M theory with the 10th spatial dimension compactified on a circle.  The origin of the F1 string, D2 brane, D4 brane and NS5 branes is simple: they come from the M2 and M5 brane either wrapping the 10th spatial dimension or not ("double" or "direct" dimensional reduction).

To explain the D0 brane, the prevailing view is that M theory also has a 0 dimensional object. This is variably called M0, MWave, pp wave, Brinkmann wave, or supergraviton. The D0 is the Kaluza Klein momentum of this object through the compact 10th spatial dimension.

As we see with the M2 and M5, each M theory object creates a pair of objects in Type IIA. So the M0 also creates a second object aside from the D0. I have seen it called a 10D pp wave or Brinkmann wave. It seems to corresponds to a gravitational plane wave (or perhaps a generic NSNS or RR wave) in the 10 noncompact dimensions.

But a gravitational wave in the 10D spacetime is just a configuration of the metric degrees of freedom (a particular coherent state of gravitons). It is a multi-string state in the string spectrum, and the string lifts to the M2 brane. The same goes for a Kalb Ramond or RR wave. So these "pp wave" descendants of the M0 seem oddly redundant with the string descendants of the M2.

This seems worthy of some explanation or discussion, but I am finding next to nothing in the literature on how these pp wave partners of D0 branes are distinct from coherent states of strings. Is there a difference here? If so, what is it? If not, how is it reasonable for there to be ambiguity about whether the propagating gravitational degrees of freedom are 0 or 1 dimensional?

And if there are these pointlike objects in superstring theory after all, doesn't that totally spoil the logic of the UV finiteness of gravitational interactions coming from stringy vertices?

Comment: D branes are solitons in the closed string fields, so is it really that odd that they would be dual to coherent states of strings?

Comment: @HarryWilson under that viewpoint, one would simply say every nonperturbative object in 10D Type IIA comes from the M2 brane, by way of the F1 string.  That sounds reasonable, but it isn't what one reads in the M Theory/Type IIA duality literature, e.g. the D4 is unambiguously described as coming from the M5.  You could say the M5 is like a magnetic soliton of "M2 fields" so that there are two routes to the D4 (down to F1 and across to D4 vs across to M5 and down to D4).  But the M0 does not seem to be treated like a soliton of the M2 at all